# Can I use IO10 as digital IO while using SPI interface?

Tags: pins, spi, arduino-galileo

If my arduino is the master device in a SPI network, hence not using the slave select SS pin, can I use the same pin as IO10?

I am actually using an Intel Galileo, with the same pinout as an Arduino Uno Rev3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use IO10 as digital IO while using SPI interface?

On AVR it must be OUTPUT when using SPI in master mode and INPUT in slave mode.

> If my arduino is the master device in a SPI network, hence not using the slave select SS pin, can I use the same pin as IO10?

The SS pin (D10) has to be OUTPUT when using SPI master mode. It can be used for chip select on the SPI bus (slave select) or some other output function.

So far the Arduino design with AVR (e.g. ATmega328). The Intel Galileo based Arduino has the following block diagram:

[image: Intel Galileo Logic Schematics]

IO10-IO14 are multiplexed from SPI1 or GPIO. This implies that the SPI SS (IO10) signal is hardwired to the SPI controller when enabled. Last, according to the [product info](https://www.arduino.cc/en/ArduinoCertified/IntelGalileo) SPI is master only. More details schematics details [here](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/galileo/sb/galileo_schematic.pdf).

Cheers!

Comment: `I am actually using an Intel Galileo` - I think Mikael's answer specifically addresses the Atmega328P processor. The Galileo may have different requirements.

Comment: Added some more info on Intel Galileo. Nick is very right about the different requirements.